# Get url of Flask App without a request

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app like the below:

```
@app.before_first_request
def set_base_url():
  global base_url
  base_url = ?? # something like myflaskapp.com or http://192.168.0.5
  # Initialize some some stuff here...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

I need to grab the full url of my app before any requests come in, in order to do a 1 time initialization of some config options. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I am using the pysaml2 library to add single sign on capabilities to my app. The library requires configuration which requires the base url as seen here: http://pysaml2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto/config.html   under the 'endpoints' key.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using [Flask-SSO](http://flask-sso.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)?  I only ask this as it makes me extremely apprehensive to add global state in that manner in Flask.

Comment: Flask-SSO uses Shibboleth as an identity provider. I have to use something different. Above was just an example to demonstrate my needs. I wouldn't be adding a global variable like that. I have an object with a 'base_url' attribute, but instead of showing code for that I though the above was a simpler example that purveyed the same need.

Comment: If you don't define `app` until the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block, you're going to get a `NameError`.

Answer (score -2):

Simply use [`app.config`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Config) to get the [`SERVER_NAME`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/#builtin-configuration-values) from your configuration:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Flask(__name__)
    domain = app.config.get('SERVER_NAME', 'some.sensible.default.domain')
    # Do things with `domain` here
```

Comment: That only works if you used SERVER_NAME to configure the instance.  If you used any other method, such as SERVER_HOST and SERVER_PORT or werkzeug run_simple then this won't work.

Comment: Yeah, this is useless